# Черный экран в pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы, pygame

При запуске программы появляется черное окно, что делать?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
import time
import random


def run():
    pygame.init
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Тест скорости набора текста")

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.w = 750
        self.h = 500
        self.reset = True
        self.active = False
        self.input_text = ''
        self.word = ''
        self.time_start = 0
        self.total_time = 0
        self.accuracy = '0%'
        self.results = 'Time:0 Accuracy:0 % Speed:0 '
        self.wpm = 0
        self.end = False
        self.HEAD_C = (255, 213, 102)
        self.TEXT_C = (240, 240, 240)
        self.RESULT_C = (255, 70, 70)

        pygame.init()
        self.open_img = pygame.image.load('Joystick.png')
        self.open_img = pygame.transform.scale(self.open_img, (self.w, self.h))

        self.bg = pygame.image.load("polygon-background.jpg")
        self.bg = pygame.transform.scale(self.bg, (500, 750))

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.w, self.h))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Тест на скорость набора текста')


def draw_text(self, screen, msg, y, fsize, color):
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, fsize)
    text = font.render(msg, 1, color)
    text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(self.w / 2, y))
    screen.blit(text, text_rect)
    pygame.display.update()


def get_sentence(self):
    f = open('sentences.txt').read()
    sentences = f.split('\n')
    sentence = random.choice(sentences)
    return sentence


def show_results(self, screen):
    if not self.end:
        # Расчет времени
        self.total_time = time.time() - self.time_start

        # Расчет точности
        count = 0
        for i, c in enumerate(self.word):
            try:
                if self.input_text[i] == c:
                    count += 1
            except:
                pass
        self.accuracy = count / len(self.word) * 100

        # Расчет количества слов в минуту
        self.wpm = len(self.input_text) * 60 / (5 * self.total_time)
        self.end = True
        print(self.total_time)

        self.results = 'Time:' + str(round(self.total_time)) + " secs   Accuracy:" + str(
            round(self.accuracy)) + "%" + ' Wpm: ' + str(round(self.wpm))

        # Загрузка иконки
        self.time_img = pygame.image.load('imac-icon.png')
        self.time_img = pygame.transform.scale(self.time_img, (150, 150))
        # screen.blit(self.time_img, (80,320))
        screen.blit(self.time_img, (self.w / 2 - 75, self.h - 140))
        self.draw_text(screen, "Reset", self.h - 70, 26, (100, 100, 100))

        print(self.results)
        pygame.display.update()


def run(self):
    self.reset_game()

    self.running = True
    while (self.running):
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0), (50, 250, 650, 50))
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.HEAD_C, (50, 250, 650, 50), 2)
        # Обновление текста пользовательского ввода
        self.draw_text(self.screen, self.input_text, 274, 26, (250, 250, 250))
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                self.running = False
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if (x >= 50 and x <= 650 and y >= 250 and y <= 300):
                    self.active = True
                    self.input_text = ''
                    self.time_start = time.time()
                    # position of reset box
                if (x >= 310 and x <= 510 and y >= 390 and self.end):
                    self.reset_game()
                    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if self.active and not self.end:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                        print(self.input_text)
                        self.show_results(self.screen)
                        print(self.results)
                        self.draw_text(self.screen, self.results, 350, 28, self.RESULT_C)
                        self.end = True

                    elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                        self.input_text = self.input_text[:-1]
                    else:
                        try:
                            self.input_text += event.unicode
                        except:
                            pass

        pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(60)

    def reset_game(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.open_img, (0, 0))

        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(1)

        self.reset = False
        self.end = False

run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понятно, зачем вам функция `run()`?

Создайте экземпляр

```
game = Game()
```

и вызовите метод `run()`

```
game.run()
```

Да, у вас проблемы в логике расчетов, но это уже совсем другой вопрос.

---

```
import sys
import time
import random
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

'''
def run():
    pygame.init
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 600))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Тест скорости набора текста")

    print(f'111') #
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
        print(f'{event.type}') #
'''
                
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
        self.w = 750
        self.h = 500
        self.reset = True
        self.active = False
        self.input_text = ''
        self.word = ''
        self.time_start = 0
        self.total_time = 0
        self.accuracy = '0%'
        self.results = 'Time:0 Accuracy:0 % Speed:0 '
        self.wpm = 0
        self.end = False
        self.HEAD_C = (255, 213, 102)
        self.TEXT_C = (240, 240, 240)
        self.RESULT_C = (255, 70, 70)

        pygame.init()
        
        self.open_img = pygame.image.load('Ok.png')            # !!!  установите Joystick.png
        
        self.open_img = pygame.transform.scale(self.open_img, (self.w, self.h))

        self.bg = pygame.image.load("lena.jpg")       # !!!  установите polygon-background.jpg
        self.bg = pygame.transform.scale(self.bg, (500, 750))

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.w, self.h))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Тест на скорость набора текста')


    def draw_text(self, screen, msg, y, fsize, color):
        font = pygame.font.Font(None, fsize)
        text = font.render(msg, 1, color)
        text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(self.w / 2, y))
        screen.blit(text, text_rect)
        pygame.display.update()


    def get_sentence(self):
        f = open('sentences.txt').read()
        sentences = f.split('\n')
        sentence = random.choice(sentences)
        return sentence


    def show_results(self, screen):
        if not self.end:
            # Расчет времени
            self.total_time = time.time() - self.time_start

            # Расчет точности
            count = 0
            for i, c in enumerate(self.word):
                try:
                    if self.input_text[i] == c:
                        count += 1
                except:
                    pass
# !!! 
            print(f'self.word = {self.word}') #
            print(f'count     = {count}') #
            self.accuracy = count / len(self.word) * 100

            # Расчет количества слов в минуту
            self.wpm = len(self.input_text) * 60 / (5 * self.total_time)
            self.end = True
            print(self.total_time)

            self.results = 'Time:' + str(round(self.total_time)) + " secs   Accuracy:" + str(
                round(self.accuracy)) + "%" + ' Wpm: ' + str(round(self.wpm))

            # Загрузка иконки
            self.time_img = pygame.image.load('imac-icon.png')
            self.time_img = pygame.transform.scale(self.time_img, (150, 150))
            # screen.blit(self.time_img, (80,320))
            screen.blit(self.time_img, (self.w / 2 - 75, self.h - 140))
            self.draw_text(screen, "Reset", self.h - 70, 26, (100, 100, 100))

            print(self.results)
            pygame.display.update()


    def run(self):
        self.reset_game()

        self.running = True
        while (self.running):
            clock = pygame.time.Clock()
            self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0), (50, 250, 650, 50))
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.HEAD_C, (50, 250, 650, 50), 2)
            # Обновление текста пользовательского ввода
            self.draw_text(self.screen, self.input_text, 274, 26, (250, 250, 250))
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    self.running = False
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    if (x >= 50 and x <= 650 and y >= 250 and y <= 300):
                        self.active = True
                        self.input_text = ''
                        self.time_start = time.time()
                        # position of reset box
                    if (x >= 310 and x <= 510 and y >= 390 and self.end):
                        self.reset_game()
                        x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if self.active and not self.end:
                        if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                            print('# ??? 111', self.input_text)
                            self.show_results(self.screen)
                            print('# ??? 222', self.results)
                            self.draw_text(self.screen, self.results, 350, 28, self.RESULT_C)
                            self.end = True

                        elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                            self.input_text = self.input_text[:-1]
                        else:
                            try:
# ???     ---->                    
                                self.input_text += event.unicode
                                print(f'{self.input_text}') #
                            except:
                                pass

            pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(60)

    def reset_game(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.open_img, (0, 0))

        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(1)

        self.reset = False
        self.end = False


game = Game()                                       # +++
game.run()                                         # +++

#run()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделал все тоже самое что и у вас, но все равно черный экран остался

Comment: @LocDoc, я не знаю что вы сделали, просто скопируйте мой пример, поменяйте изображения на свои и запустите его. Потом смотрите на изменения, который я сделал.

Comment: Так и сделал...

Answer (score 1):

У Вас идёт код игры который что либо рисует на экран в классе, но вы этот класс не иницылизируете, поэтому у вас только создаёться чёрный экран на котором ничего не рисуеться